# sql not showing null values in between query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am using postgres and I have a query to show some data for a salesrep between two dates but i also need to show the ones that have no sales and i have this:

```
    SELECT SALESREP.SALESREPID, COALESCE(SUM(ORDERLINE.QUANTITY),0) AS TOTALSALES, COALESCE(SUM(ORDERLINE.QUANTITY*ORDERLINE.UNITSELLINGPRICE),0) AS TOTALVALUE
FROM SHOPORDER
right JOIN SALESREP ON SALESREP.SALESREPID = SHOPORDER.SALESREPID 
left  JOIN ORDERLINE ON ORDERLINE.SHOPORDERID=SHOPORDER.SHOPORDERID
WHERE
SHOPORDER.ORDERDATE BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2016-04-30' or SHOPORDER.ORDERDATE is null
GROUP BY SALESREP.SALESREPID
ORDER BY TOTALVALUE desc
```

and it gives me the following results:

```
3;7;287.00
2;9;190.88
1;6;147.00
4;1;59.00
5;0;0
```

but when i try to put a date in 2017 it only appears the fifth row.
Is there a way to appear all 5 rows with 0s or not at all as no salesrep has sales in 2017?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you're looking to use the CASE statement:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html

Example:

```
postgres=# create table t (x int );
CREATE TABLE
postgres=# insert into t values (1);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into t values (NULL);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# insert into t values (3);
INSERT 0 1
postgres=# select * from t;
 x
---
 1

 3
(3 rows)

postgres=# select (CASE WHEN x is NULL THEN 0 ELSE x END) from t;
 x
---
 1
 0
 3
(3 rows)
```